# Unable to redirect Not Found Page to 404.php (gae php yaml)

Tags: php, google-app-engine, http-status-code-404, yaml

I have the following error when I run WEBSITE/images/weq, i think it should be caught and redirect to 404.php, but it does not work, please help !!

Error: Not Found
The requested URL /images/weq was not found on this server.

```
application: smile-bee-999
version: 1
runtime: php55
api_version: 1

default_expiration: "3d"

handlers:

- url: /
  script: index.php

- url: /favicon.ico
  static_files: favicon.ico
  upload: favicon.ico

- url: /sitemap.xml
  static_files: sitemap.xml
  upload: sitemap.xml  

- url: /robots.txt
  static_files: robots.txt
  upload: robots.txt  

- url: /images
  static_dir: images

- url: /css
  mime_type: text/css
  static_dir: css

- url: /font
  mime_type: text/font
  static_dir: font

- url: /font-awesome/css
  mime_type: text/css
  static_dir: font-awesome/css  

- url: /js
  mime_type: text/javascript
  static_dir: js

- url: /index.php
  script: index.php

- url: /about.php
  script: about.php

- url: /product.php
  script: product.php

- url: /contact.php
  script: contact.php

- url: /.*
  script: 404.php
```

Comment: Do you actually have a file called "weq" in your [project root]/images folder?

Comment: no weq file in the folder, therefore, I expect it will be redirected to 404 ...

Comment: Argh I see. Unfortunately I don't think you can specify a custom 404 file for static files as Anhuin@ pointed out. Note that the error page you see does return HTTP 404 though.

Answer (score 1):

Your question isn't really clear, I guess your 404 error handler is working for your handlers except the one with a static_dir ?

**If YES**:
I don't think you can make this work with static_dir because file served as static are served without any handler configuration. Therefore you cannot specify your own 404 handler.

**If NO**:
Take a look at
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/config/appconfig#PHP_app_yaml_Custom_error_responses

Comment: Many thanks ... it works when I create folder (static_dir) and move all the folders (css/js/images)  to this static_dir.